# Magento 2.3 Gift card rest API for add to cart

Tags: magento2.3, addtocart, gift-card

I have checked **https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_23.html#/giftCardAccountGiftCardAccountManagementV1** 
for api but it is not clear here where to pass recipient name,email.message details.

Can someone tell me about gift card purchase flow in `magento 2.3` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link for gift card purchase flow in Magento 2.3
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-gift-card-workflow.html
It's an official link of dev docs (Magento).
For any queries, you can add that to the comment.

Answer (score 0):

`POST /rest/V1/carts/mine/items`

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "giftcard_item_option": 
          {
            "giftcard_amount": 50.0000,
            "giftcard_sender_name": "test",
            "giftcard_recipient_name": "test",
            "giftcard_sender_email": "test@test.com",
            "giftcard_recipient_email": "test@test.com",
            "giftcard_message": "magento is stupid"
          }
        
      }
    },
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": {{YOUR_QUOTE_ID_HERE}},
    "sku": {{YOUR_SKU_HERE}}
  }
}
```